# Nice concise way to convert list of keys and lists of values into list of anonymous hashes

Tags: perl

So I have this:

```
@keys = qw/foo bar baz/
@values = ( [1,2,3], [4,5,6], ... )
```

And I would like to convert it to:

```
{ foo => 1, bar => 2, baz => 3 }, { foo => 4, bar => 5, baz => 6 }, ...
```

What is a nice, concise, idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want array of hashes, so you can use `map` to transform `@values` array,

```
my @keys = qw/foo bar baz/;
my @values = ( [1,2,3], [4,5,6] );
my @AoH = map { my %h; @h{@keys} = @$_; \%h } @values;
```

Comment: `my @AoH = map { my $h; @$h{@keys} = @$_; $h } @values;` same thing using $h hashref.

Comment: I was initially hoping to avoid the use of a named temporary variable, but seeing it now it isn't too much extra code.

Comment: List::Moreutils can do this if you don't want to use extra variable.

Comment: ^-- Specifically: `use List::MoreUtils 'zip';` followed by `my @AoH = map { { zip @keys, @$_ } } @values;` Personally, I think the hash slice is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( zip );

my @keys = qw( foo bar baz );
my @values = ( [1,2,3], [4,5,6] );
my @hashes = map +{ zip @keys, @$_ }, @values;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( zip );

my @keys = qw( foo bar baz );
my @values = ( [1,2,3], [4,5,6] );
my @hashes = map { { zip @keys, @$_ } } @values;
```

Comment: This is a fixed version of @Oesor's deleted post. If he undeletes his post and lets me know, I'll delete mine.

Comment: It's no big deal - I didn't have enough coffee this morning and deleted mine in lieu of fixing it.